# Django cache stores different key on get params

Tags: python, django, caching, django-redis

I am using django cache with django-redis-cache as a backend.

with:

```
@cache_page(60*60*24)
```

decorator on views.

Now the issue I am facing is every get request is being stored with a different key in redis. 
I have to display the same page for any get parameters. Is there any way to force cache to ignore get parameters while serving and making the key.

Answer (score 0):

There's of course "a way" to compute a same cache key whatever the request's querystring, but it requires a bit of work - you'll have to rewrite your own `cache_page` implementation based on the low-level cache API (which is documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api). You may also read the source code for the `CacheMiddleware` (upon which `cache_page` is built).

Now I have to say I don't get the point of ignoring the querystring when generating the cache key for a page cache.

Comment: I actually am using something like a secret login based on GET parameters and using it to warmup the cache from a cron-type python script. (The page loads take around 25mins each).